# How to make landing page 100% of viewport?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a landing page, and it needs to be 100% of viewport, [example](http://celine-bonin.fr/) .
As you can see, picture is 100% of width and height.

I've succeed to make it 100% of width, but for height I haven't. Picture is bigger than my viewport.

This is my css [code](http://jsfiddle.net/LtMpw/3/) :

```
body {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
}

#main_wrapper {
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;
    float:left;
    background-image: url("http://imgur.com/B2y6wuI");
     background-position: center top;
    background-size: 100% auto;
}

#wrapper {
    width:970px;
    height:1000px;
    margin:0 auto 0 auto;
}

#landing {
    width:100%;
    height:800px;

}
```

Comment: [Like that?](http://jsfiddle.net/LtMpw/4/)

Comment: I would see if this helps http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: @DavidCorbin no, maybe I wasn't clear. 
I don't want my whole page to have single image, I just want for my landing page to be 100%.

Comment: Oh sorry, then Barto's post below should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are working with html5/css3 you can use height:100vh (instead of %... vh = viewport height)... EDIT: depending on what browsers you want to support.. http://caniuse.com/viewport-units

Answer (score 1):

with css3 you can

```
#main-wrapper{ 
  background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you are trying to do here? If you are trying to have a full size background image that scales to the width and height of your viewport, then a lot of your CSS is unnecessary. There is certainly more than one way to skin a cat but in this case CSS3 allows us to use

`background-size: cover;`

http://jsfiddle.net/LtMpw/6/